# PHP Function to Create Dynamic SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a lot of repetitive code that inserts and selects data from my MySQL database. Out of curiosity, is it possible to create a PHP function that can take the `table`, `columns`, and `rows` as parameters and generate the SQL statement. A completely dynamic SQL statement generator, if you will.

For example:

```
function PushData($table, $columns, $values)
{
    // insert data
}
```

Furthermore, is the opposite possible. A function that can select and return data.

```
function PullData($table, $columns, $rowID)
{
    // grab data
    return data;
}
```

Is something like this possible? If so, would this be something worth doing?

Comment: You can do this in Zend. But I imagine that's extreme overkill for what your looking for.

Comment: Yes it is possible, i work with such functions every day. But be carefull about the sql injection!

Comment: It is called a Query Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that i'm not sure that it will work.

```
function PushData($table, $columns, $values)
{
    $question_mark = count($columns)-1;
    $question_mark_array = array_fill(0, $question_mark, '?');

    $valueEscapedTrimed = array();

    foreach($values as $value)
    {
        $value=trim($value);
        $valueEscapedTrimed[] = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding = 'UTF-8' );
    }

    $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$table. '(' .implode(' ',$columns). ') VALUES ('.implode(',',$question_mark_array).') \' ' ;

    foreach($valueEscapedTrimed as $value)
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue('?', $value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->CloseCursor();
        $stmt=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't the `$valueEscapedTrimed`  be out of scope and therefore unaccessible to the second foreach loop?

Comment: I think i need to initialize the array . See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone was curious like I was, I made a working example of both functions. Special thanks to Michael's answer for putting me in the right direction.

**Insert Data Function**

```
function PushData($conn, $table, $columns, $values)
{
  $column_count = count($columns);
  $overwriteArr = array_fill(0, $column_count, '?');

  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($columns); $i++)
  {
    $columns[$i] = trim($columns[$i]);
    $columns[$i] = '`' . $columns[$i] . '`';
  }

  $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} (" . implode(',', $columns) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',', $overwriteArr) . ")";

  foreach ($values as $value)
  {
    $value = trim($value);
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);
    $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding = 'UTF-8');
    $value = '"' . $value . '"';
    $query = preg_replace('/\?/', $value, $query, 1);
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  return $result;
}
```

**Select Data Function**

```
function PullData($conn, $table, $columns, $operand_column, $operand_value)
{
  $columns = implode(',', $columns);
  $sql = "SELECT {$columns} FROM {$table} WHERE {$operand_column} = {$operand_value}";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  return $result;
}
```